# How to solve JS Regex not working during keypress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

I have some requirement as below:

1. Minimum character is 3 and maximum is 8.
2. Only accept Capital Letter and Underscore.
3. The 1st three (3) characters must be Uppercase.

Example acceptable input: "SAL", "SAL_", "SAL_G"

The problem now:

1. How to control user must enter compulsory fill 1st three character with Uppercase?
2. The underscore is not appear when press at the keyboard

[image]

Code

```js
$('#myInput').on("keypress", function(e) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$")
  var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
  if (regex.test(str)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput" minlength="3" maxlength="8">
```

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp()` for static regular expressions, it should only be used when creating it dynamically from variables. Use a RegExp literal.

Comment: `str` is just the last character that the user typed, not the whole input. Why are you using a multi-character regexp to test it?

Comment: To get the whole input use `this.value`.

Comment: Based on your requirements, I recommend `^[A-Z]{3}[A-Z_]{0,5}$` for the regex pattern

Comment: @CAustin The problem with using that in the `keypress` event is that it won't let you type the first 2 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have used `input` event basically if you used `keypress` then it will not works with other touch keyboards.

Also `keypress` not supports to copy pasted content also [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ayK.png)

So you can probably try below code let me know if this helps.

#### Try below snippet

```js
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#myInput");
inputElements.forEach((inputElement) => {
  inputElement.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    let inputText = event.target.value;
    let pregExpr = /[^A-Z]/g;
    if (inputText.length > 3) {
      pregExpr = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    }
    let sanitizedText = inputText.replace(pregExpr, "");
    if (sanitizedText.length > 2) {
      var trimmedString = sanitizedText.substring(0, 3);
      sanitizedText = trimmedString + "_" + sanitizedText.slice(3);
    }
    event.target.value = sanitizedText;
  });

  inputElement.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Backspace") {
      let inputText = inputElement.value;
      if (inputText.endsWith("_")) {
        let newText = inputText.substring(0, inputText.length - 2);
        inputElement.value = newText;
      } else if (inputText.length > 0) {
        let newText = inputText.substring(0, inputText.length - 1);
        inputElement.value = newText;
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput" minlength="3" maxlength="8">
```

##### OLD CODE VERSION

```js
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#myInput");
inputElements.forEach((inputElement) => {
  inputElement.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    const inputText = event.target.value;
    let pregExpr = /[^A-Z]/g;
    if (inputText.length > 3) {
      pregExpr = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    }
    let sanitizedText = inputText.replace(pregExpr, "");
    if (sanitizedText.length > 2) {
      var trimmedString = sanitizedText.substring(0, 3);
      sanitizedText = trimmedString + "_" + sanitizedText.slice(3);
    }
    event.target.value = sanitizedText;
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput" minlength="3" maxlength="8">
```

Comment: Hi, just wanna know, if user wrongly input the information, how to delete (backspace) the input the underscore and the character before it. I just can delete character after the underscore.

Comment: @mastersuse I have altered code. Please look once

Comment: Sorry for interrupt, the new code accepting integer, symbol? :-D

Comment: Yes missed one case now try above code @mastersuse